# How to make a counter reset when he reaches a certain value?

Tags: vhdl, counter

I have this code which counts clock cycles between two asychronous (and random ) trigger events. I wish to make the counter stop if it reaches the value 1200d and reset to zero.
The code is provided without my attempts to reset the counter.

I've tried to add an  ( if counter reaches 1200 then counter to be done zero ) statement in the clock process but no result.

I simulate with two cases. First: I have a pair of trigger events with 85 clock cycles between them  and the second pair of trigger events with 1500 clock cycles between them . In the second case I want the counter to stop when it reaches 1200 and go back to 0.

I apologise but I can't yet post an image of my simulation
Thanks in advance for any help.

#### The module

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity main is
  Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
  trigger : in  STD_LOGIC;
  output : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0)  );
end main;
architecture Behavioral of main is
signal counter : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0) := "000000000000";
signal enable : STD_LOGIC:='0'; 
begin
  trigger_proc : process(trigger)  
    variable state : std_logic := '0';
    begin   
      if(falling_edge(trigger))then
        if(state = '0')then
          enable <= '1'; 
          state := '1';
        elsif(state = '1')then
          enable <= '0';
          state := '0';
        end if;
      end if;
    end process;
  counter_proc : process(clk)
    begin
      if(rising_edge(clk))then
        if(enable =  '1')then
          counter <= counter + "1"; 
        elsif(enable = '0'  )then
          counter <= "000000000000";
        end if; 
      end if;  
    end process;
  output <= counter;
end Behavioral;
```

and the **TEST BENCH**

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
ENTITY test IS
END test;
ARCHITECTURE behavior OF test IS 
  COMPONENT main
    PORT(
      clk : IN  std_logic;
      trigger : IN  std_logic;
      output : OUT  std_logic_vector(11 downto 0)
    );
  END COMPONENT;
  signal clk : std_logic := '0';
  signal trigger : std_logic := '1';
  signal output : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
  constant clk_period : time := 25 ns;
  BEGIN
    kyklwma: main PORT MAP (
      clk => clk,
      trigger => trigger,
      output => output 
    );
    clk_process :process
      begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;
    end process;
    trigger_stim: process 
      begin      
        wait for 100 ns;    
        trigger <= '0';-- first trigger event with  counter <1200
        wait for clk_period;
        trigger <= '1';
        wait for clk_period*85;
        trigger <= '0';--second trigger event with  counter <1200
        wait for clk_period;
        trigger <= '1';
        wait for 10000 ns;
        trigger <= '0';-- first trigger event with counter > 1200
        wait for clk_period;
        trigger <= '1';
        wait for clk_period*1500;
        trigger <= '0';--second   trigger event with counter > 1200
        wait for clk_period;
        trigger <= '1';
        wait;
    end process;
END;
```

Comment: At least for me, it is unclear what your problem is. What does "no result" mean?

Comment: @mfro Hello , at the test bench i have build a trigger sequence for the counter to count to 85 and another  one to count to  1500d . What i am trying to do is to make him stop when he passes 1200d and reset to 0d   .

Comment: SO expects that you show - in your code - what you tried, what you expected and what you've seen. Then people will be happy to show you how your code can be improved to achieve what you wanted

Comment: You're not using numeric_std or integers for a problem that requires arithmetic and numeric comparisons. You should really show your attempt of resetting the counter, so we can show you in great detail why anyone using std_logic_(un)signed for new code past 1995 hasn't got a clue what they're doing.